# Failed to build wxWidgets wxWebView on OSX using wxMac

Tags: c++, cmake, homebrew, wxwidgets

I'm attempting to construct a simple C++ web window using wxWebView on OSX.  I'm using the wxMac install from HomeBrew.  The build fails to find the necessary overridden class to handle the native wxWebView.  The result is that wxWebView is undefined.

```
error: unknown type name 'wxWebView'; did you mean 'WebView'?
  wxWebView *foo = nullptr;
```

The webview is encapsulated in a wxDialog message as follows:

```
#ifndef _IRVIZWIN_H_
#define _IRVIZWIN_H_

//-- WX HEADERS
#include <wx/artprov.h>
#include <wx/xrc/xmlres.h>
#include <wx/string.h>
#include <wx/listbox.h>
#include <wx/gdicmn.h>
#include <wx/font.h>
#include <wx/colour.h>
#include <wx/settings.h>
#include <wx/sizer.h>
#include <wx/dirctrl.h>
#include <wx/aui/auibook.h>
#include <wx/stattext.h>
#include <wx/frame.h>
#include <wx/panel.h>
#include <wx/textctrl.h>
#include <wx/choice.h>
#include <wx/statline.h>
#include <wx/button.h>
#include <wx/dialog.h>
#include <wx/checkbox.h>
#include <wx/msgdlg.h>
#include <wx/stc/stc.h>
#include <wx/webview.h>
#include <wx/webviewarchivehandler.h>
#include <wx/webviewfshandler.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
#include <wx/wx.h>
#endif

class IRVizWin : public wxDialog {
private:
  // private data
  wxWebView* m_browser;     //< browser handler

  /// Declares the event table
  wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();

  // button handlers
  /// handles the 'ok' button press
  void OnPressOk( wxCommandEvent& ok );

  protected:
  // window handlers
  wxBoxSizer *OuterSizer;   ///< outer window sizer
  wxBoxSizer *InnerSizer;   ///< inner window sizer
  wxScrolledWindow *Wnd;    ///< main scrolled window

  wxStaticLine *FinalStaticLine;  ///< final static line

  // buttons
  wxStdDialogButtonSizer* m_irbuttonsizer;  ///< button sizer
  wxButton* m_irOK;                         ///< OK button

public:
  IRVizWin(wxWindow* parent,
           wxWindowID id = wxID_ANY,
           const wxString& title = wxT("IR Visualization"),
           const wxPoint& pos = wxDefaultPosition,
           const wxSize& size = wxDefaultSize,
           long style = wxDEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE);
  ~IRVizWin();
};

#endif
```

```
#include "IRVizWin.h"

// Event Table
wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(IRVizWin, wxDialog)
  EVT_BUTTON(wxID_OK, IRVizWin::OnPressOk)
wxEND_EVENT_TABLE()

IRVizWin::IRVizWin(wxWindow *parent,
                   wxWindowID id,
                   const wxString& title,
                   const wxPoint& pos,
                   const wxSize& size,
                   long style)
  : wxDialog( parent, id, title, pos, size, style ){

  // init the internals
  this->SetLayoutAdaptationMode(wxDIALOG_ADAPTATION_MODE_ENABLED);
  this->SetSizeHints( wxDefaultSize, wxDefaultSize );

  // create the outer sizer
  OuterSizer = new wxBoxSizer( wxVERTICAL );

  // create the scrolled window
  Wnd = new wxScrolledWindow( this,
                              wxID_ANY,
                              wxDefaultPosition,
                              wxDefaultSize,
                              0,
                              wxT("scroll"));

  // create the inner sizer
  InnerSizer = new wxBoxSizer( wxVERTICAL );

  // setup the browser window
  m_browser = WebView::New(this, wxID_ANY, wxT("http://www.stackoverflow.com/"),
                           wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxWebViewBackendDefault);
  // do something with the browser

  // add the final static line
  FinalStaticLine = new wxStaticLine( Wnd,
                                      wxID_ANY,
                                      wxDefaultPosition,
                                      wxDefaultSize,
                                      wxLI_HORIZONTAL );
  InnerSizer->Add( FinalStaticLine, 1, wxEXPAND | wxALL, 5 );

  // setup all the buttons
  m_irbuttonsizer = new wxStdDialogButtonSizer();
  m_irOK = new wxButton( Wnd, wxID_OK );
  m_irbuttonsizer->AddButton( m_irOK );
  m_irbuttonsizer->Realize();

  InnerSizer->Add( m_irbuttonsizer, 1, wxEXPAND, 5 );

  // draw the diag box until we get more info
  Wnd->SetScrollbars(20,20,50,50);
  Wnd->SetSizer( InnerSizer );
  Wnd->SetAutoLayout(true);
  Wnd->Layout();

  OuterSizer->Add( Wnd, 1, wxEXPAND | wxALL, 5 );
  this->SetSizer( OuterSizer );
  this->SetAutoLayout(true);
  this->Layout();
}

void IRVizWin::OnPressOk( wxCommandEvent& ok ){
  this->EndModal( wxID_OK );
}

IRVizWin::~IRVizWin(){
}
```

This is my wxMac installed version info:

```
wxmac: stable 3.0.5 (bottled), HEAD
Cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit (wxWidgets for macOS)
https://www.wxwidgets.org
/usr/local/Cellar/wxmac/3.0.4_2 (810 files, 22.9MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2020-01-17 at 06:48:37
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/wxmac.rb
```

From the ruby script in the Homebrew repo, it appears that wxWidgets is built with wxWebView enabled for OSX.  I'm using the following CMake snippet to build it:

```
set (VizSrcs
IRVizWin.cpp
)
find_package(wxWidgets COMPONENTS net adv aui core gl html propgrid qa ribbon richtext stc xrc base webview REQUIRED)
IF(wxWidgets_FOUND)
  INCLUDE("${wxWidgets_USE_FILE}")
  include_directories ( . )
  message(STATUS " wxWidgets Include: ${wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
  include_directories (${wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  add_library(VizObjs OBJECT ${VizSrcs})
ELSE(wxWidgets_FOUND)
  MESSAGE("wxWidgets not found!")
ENDIF(wxWidgets_FOUND)
```

Does wxMac under HomeBrew support wxWebView?  If so, what am I missing?

Comment: `m_browser = WebView::New(`... This can't be right, can it? You need `m_browser = wxWebView::New(`.

Comment: You should check if `wxUSE_WEBVIEW` is 1 in your build, e.g. by checking it with `#if` and giving `#error "Yes, it is 1"`.

Comment: It appears to be enabled: ```error: "Yes, it is 1"
#error "Yes, it is 1"```

Comment: @catalin, you are correct.  That was a typo on my part.  The build still fails however.

Comment: It appears that the Homebrew build enables WebKit, but not WebView:  Per the HomeBrew ruby script, ```--enable-webkit``` is enabled but not ```--enable-webview```

Comment: @defineundef, the best way is to compile the library yourself...

Comment: @Igor, I was hoping to avoid that and use the native platform binaries on Darwin and Linux

Comment: @defineundef, well, you WILL be using the native binaries - whether you compile it yourself or use some 3rd party tool to install them. As long as you properly configured it and use an appropriate SDK you will have a platform-native executable.

Comment: @igor, s/binaries/packages//

Comment: @defineundef, doesn';t matter. You program will be packaged as OSX bundle with everything in it. SO it doesn't matter how you do the wxWidgets. But when YOU compile it - you will be guaranteed that the library will contain whatever features YOU want.

Comment: As an example - you may not need the scintilla at all or any of the advanced controls wxWidgets provides. Or you may not need the aui library. One more time - compiling yourself will guarantee that everything will work for your application.

Comment: @Igor, thanks that wasn't helpful.  Nor did it answer my original question.

Comment: @defineundef, you should try to compile the library yourself from sources and then compile the webview sample provided and then compile your application. Did you try it?

Comment: @Igor.  Yes.  That works.  The question is in regard to the HomeBrew package, not binaries built from source.  It appears that the HomeBrew package doesn't support wxWebView.

Comment: @defineundef, it is quite possible that whoever made those packaes created a different library for the webview and it is not available thru the default install of wxWidgets. That's why it is best to compile everything yourself, or know what libraries to install before trying.That's also true for *nix as well.